# when i try to generate signed Bundle / APK, "app not installed" and stopped. how to fix it

Tags: android, installation, build.gradle, android-jetpack-compose, version

I updated compose for the purpose that it became TextField non-working
After the upgrade, I had to upgrade Java from 1_8 to 11,
because it showed me an incompatibility error, or I needed Java 11.
when I generate signed Bundle / APK from Build menu
For the first time this error did not work with all solutions
The application does not install (app not installed)
The key.jks file has no problems it’s the same old
And for all the activities that need to be exported you set them (android:exported="true").

```
<application
    android:name="iq.myapp.android.myapp"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.myapp.SplashScreen"
    android:extractNativeLibs="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity
        android:name="iq.myapp.android.ui.main.MainActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:configChanges="uiMode"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.myapp.SplashScreen"
        tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="iq.myapp.android.utils.casting.RemoteControlActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:immersive="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:parentActivityName="iq.myapp.android.ui.main.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:showOnLockScreen="true"
        android:taskAffinity=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.myapp"
        tools:ignore="Instantiatable" />

    <activity android:name=".ui.auth.AuthActivity"
        android:label="AppAuth"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.myapp"
        tools:ignore="RedundantLabel"
        android:exported="true">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
        tools:node="replace"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:ignore="MissingClass">
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme=""
                android:host=""/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
    android:name=".ui.player.PlayerActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.myapp" />


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
        android:value="iq.myapp.android.utils.casting.CastOptionsProvider" />
</application>
```

Update:

The problem was due to this line (compileSdkPreview = "UpsideDownCake") when updating gradle to version 8.
the issue was solved by downgrading gradle version to 7.5
and delete this line
and the problem is solved.

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: no error message@zomega

Comment: this happened exactly when I updated my Java version from 1_8 to 11, I am not sure if this could be the reason @zomega

Comment: Execute `./gradlew assemblerelease` in AndoridStudio Terminal then it should show an error message if it fails.

Comment: can you please attach any error if in  build or run have came up with it

Comment: thanks to everyone who tried to help, problem solved, and updated the question.